# Applying a google sheets macro to multiple google sheet files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

Column "A" has a the list of a hundred different google sheets or IDs
I have the apps script for a macro I created that needs to be ran on the "tab 2" of all 100 google sheets

Is it possible to create a script that goes through each and every one of those files and applies the macro?
If not, is there a quick and easy way for me to access the macro in each google sheet?

Here is the Macro code as requested - changed some info.

```
function Combined () {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AW:AW').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showColumns(47, 1);
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=ifs(H2="Brossard", "111",H2="Calgary", "222",H2="Edmonton", "333",H2="Gatineau", "444",H2="Halifax", "555",H2="London", "666",H2="Montreal", "777",H2="Oakville", "888",H2="Ottawa", "999",H2="Quebec", "111",H2="Regina", "222",H2="Saint John", "333",H2="Saskatoon", "444",H2="St. John\'s", "555",H2="Surrey", "666",H2="Toronto Downtown", "777",H2="Truro", "888",H2="Vancouver", "999",H2="Vaughan", "111",H2="Victoria", "222",H2="Waterloo", "333",H2="Windsor", "444",H2="Winnipeg", "555",H2="Waterloo", "666",H2="Windsor", "777",H2="Winnipeg", "888")');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('AV2:AV1000'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV:AV').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());
  spreadsheet.getRange('AW:AW').activate();
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B:B').activate();
  var allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'B:B';
  });
  var protection = matchingProtections[0];
  protection.addEditors(['abc@abc.com', 'abc@abc.com']);
  allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'B:B';
  });
  protection = matchingProtections[0];
  allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'A:A';
  });
  protection = matchingProtections[0];
  protection.addEditors(['abc@abc.com', 'abc@abc.com']);
  allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'A:A';
  });
  protection = matchingProtections[0];
  spreadsheet.getRange('AW:AW').activate();
  allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'AV:AV';
  });
  protection = matchingProtections[0];
  protection.addEditors(['abc@abc.com', 'abc@abc.com']);
  allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'AV:AV';
  });
  protection = matchingProtections[0];
  spreadsheet.getRange('C1:AW1').activate();
  allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'C1:AV1';
  });
  protection = matchingProtections[0];
  protection.addEditors(['abc@abc.com', 'abc@abc.com']);
  allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'C1:AV1';
  });
  protection = matchingProtections[0];
}
```

Comment: Is there just one macro? If there is then please share it.

Comment: @Cooper updated!

Comment: Really the first thing you need to do is to rewrite that macro without using activate or getActiveSpreadsheet.  Change the code in your script when you're done.

Comment: @Cooper Im not familiar with VBA or writing scripts, the code above if the auto generated code from the script editor once I recorded my macro based on clicks. If I remove activate and getActiveSpreadsheet won't that break the macro?

Comment: Oh the assumption I make here is that you are a programmer or at least  you desirie to be a programmer. If that's not true, then I apologize and I'll just move on to another question.

Comment: @Cooper sorry was just looking for some help ... 
do you have any resources I could read into to learn this

Comment: Have you read the Google Apps Script [Spreadsheet Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: The problem is that macros while being easy to create really suck as scripts. And turning them into working scripts is kind of a nuisance but It leads to a much more useable script.  I suspect that if you try to automate this script to run with 100 spreadsheets you'll ultimately get to the point where you will have to rewrite it any way because you will probably hit the time out.

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  learning resources

Comment: Have the comments above helped? Also, is getting each id and using [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) an option to run the script on each spreadsheet?

Comment: @Kessy the comments above have helped to give direction, but I will definitely be trying openById Thanks!

Comment: So what i've done is created a new function to open the sheets using openById on the active spreadsheet, but my problem now is that the rest of the code is also using getActiveSheet for the macro. is there anything i can replace getActiveSheet with so it uses the sheet I opened using openById? @cooper

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would share your progress.

Comment: Have you made any progress? Can you share your updated code editing the question and providing all the information related to new updates?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple start:

```
function Combined () {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.showColumns(47,1);
  sh.getRange(2,48).setFormula('=ifs(H2="Brossard", "111",H2="Calgary", "222",H2="Edmonton", "333",H2="Gatineau", "444",H2="Halifax", "555",H2="London", "666",H2="Montreal", "777",H2="Oakville", "888",H2="Ottawa", "999",H2="Quebec", "111",H2="Regina", "222",H2="Saint John", "333",H2="Saskatoon", "444",H2="St. John\'s", "555",H2="Surrey", "666",H2="Toronto Downtown", "777",H2="Truro", "888",H2="Vancouver", "999",H2="Vaughan", "111",H2="Victoria", "222",H2="Waterloo", "333",H2="Windsor", "444",H2="Winnipeg", "555",H2="Waterloo", "666",H2="Windsor", "777",H2="Winnipeg", "888")');
```